# ionic serve results in white screen

Tags: ionic-framework

Anyone else encountering this? After running `ionic serve -cs` the server spins up but a blank webpage gets shown with no errors in the console.

Here is my setup:

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.12
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Cordova Platforms               : browser 4.0.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v8.1.3
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b 
ios-deploy : 1.9.0 
ios-sim    : 5.0.9 
npm        : 5.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. For some reason the cli command `ionic serve` defaults to `--address 0.0.0.0`. When the browser auto launches it uses `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0`. Replaced `localhost` with `0.0.0.0` and fixed my problem.